# How to consume SOAP service with custom header

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I need to consume a SOAP service from a vendor. I had created a proxy service with the WSDL in visual studio, instantiated the client class, called the action method, and got the response. Everything works fine until the vendor asks for an access token in the soap envelop header. I am able to get the access token from them on another service call but how do I add it to the soap request header?
Here is the structure of the header from the vendor:

```
<SOAP:Header> 
    <SOAP-SEC:Security SOAP:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:SecuredKey ValueType="..." EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
        {ACCESS TOKEN}
      </wsse:SecuredKey>
    </SOAP-Sec:Security>
  </SOAP:Header>
  <SOAP:Body/>
</SOAP:Envelop>
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is by using a string replace in a template. Store the message as a resource in your project (e.g. in Resources.resx or save as file and set set build action to embedded resource). The template looks like this:

```
<SOAP:Header> 
    <SOAP-SEC:Security SOAP:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:SecuredKey ValueType="..." EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
        {ACCESS TOKEN}
      </wsse:SecuredKey>
    </SOAP-Sec:Security>
  </SOAP:Header>
  <SOAP:Body/>
</SOAP:Envelop>
```

Load the template as string from your resource, then call the webservice to obtain an access token and do and replace *{ACCESS TOKEN}* with the actual access token. You can now send the soap message using e.g. `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` or `System.Net.WebClient`.

Example using `WebClient`

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var result = client.UploadString("http://your.target/endpoint", yourXDocument.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));                
    return XDocument.Parse(result);
}
```

The `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting` doesn't try to pretty print the `XDocument` which can be important when using a signed xml document with WS-Security. Not sure if that applies in your case.

Comment: can you give an example please? I looked online in the last couple of days and all I found is creating the XmlDocument with the soap xml and using HttpWebRequest to make the actual request. I can't find one example that uses HttpClient.

Comment: I was only using `HttpClient` as one possibility. You can use `HttpWebRequest`  or `WebClient` as well. I've updated my answer with an example